# How to parse out a period at the end of a URL in a sentence?

Tags: php, regex

Here's what I have so far:

```
/(^|\s)(http:\/\/(\S+)(?!(.png|.gif|.jpg)($|\.\s|\.$|\s)))($|\.\s|\.$|\s)/i
```

And I'm replacing it like so:

```
'$1<a href="$2">$2</a>$6'
```

Sometimes, my users type something like this: http://google.com. <- How do I avoid including that final period without parsing out other periods that are in URLs?

Also, in case you're wondering what the .gif .png etc is for, I'm parsing out images to automatically create  elements.

Edit:
This is for PHP.

This is for a forum where users post lots of things including links. It successfully handles every situation except for punctuation after the URL.

Edit 2:
Parse out might be the wrong word. I'm not trying to remove the punctuation, just separate it from the URL so I can display a working link to my users.

Edit 3:
http://daringfireball.net/2010/07/improved_regex_for_matching_urls
I haven't testing fully yet, but it seems to work. I'll make it a solution after I've tested. Or if someone else wants points, feel free to test and I'll vote for your solution.

Comment: If you don't have to use regex, a more simple and efficient solution is to check if the last char of the string is a full stop and then remove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So updated solution:

```
/\b(http:\/\/(\S+(?<!\.)(?=(?:$|\s|\.(?:$|\s)))))(?<!(?:\.(?:png|gif|jpg)))/i
```

See it [here online on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2v6hj)

I replaced your `(^|\s)` by `\b` thats a word boundary that is exactly what you want here.

To your `(\S+)` I changed to `(\S+(?<!\.)(?=(?:$|\s|\.(?:$|\s))))`. Basically I match every non whitespace till there is `$|\s|\.(?:$|\s)` ahead and no dot on the left (the `(?<!\.)` part).

The following look around needs to be a look behind.

Then I cleaned your brackets and alternations a bit up and used some non capturing groups (the groups that start with `(?:`)

So for your test string `users type something like this: http://google.com. <- How do I avoid` it will match `http://google.com` with this in the first group and `google.com` in the second group.

Comment: I like a lot of these changes, but it's failing when there's more than one URL in the string. It's keeping the second URL as a string (which my original handled correctly).

Comment: @Stephane So, it was not failing on more than one URL, it was failing on URLs without dot at the end. Corrected the regex and updated the Regexr link. Is a bit more complicated now.

Answer (score 1):

PHP solution:

```
$line = 'http://www.google.com.';

echo preg_replace(
    "/(\s*)((http:\/\/)?(\S+?(.png|.gif|.jpg)?))(\W*)$/i", 
    '$1<a href="$2">$2</a>$6', 
    $line), "\n";
```

Comment: I'm using this to replace URLs with links in PHP. I don't want to strip anything.

Comment: Ok, but can you match and create a link out of what I'm typing right now http://google.com. It's not always at the end! Stackoverflow gets it right!

Comment: It still isn't working correctly. Here is the test string: http://google.com. And http://google.png. And http://google.com (SO is removing http://

Comment: You're moving the goal posts.  Could you better layout your test cases and expected results?  For example, what do you expect to happen when a user creates a link to google.png?  Is your code supposed to know whether .png is a valid TLD; Do you want it to stick "http://" in when it's missing?; etc.

Comment: Sorry. (and thanks) What I want is for any number of URLs to be replaced with anchors even if there's trailing punctuation. Right now, I have it so that it looks for white-space and that works ok, but I have had a few users use URLs in sentences and the ending period gets included in the href which breaks the link. Is that clearer? The image thing isn't relevant. I was just trying to explain what that regex was already doing.